# How to place existing columns under a hierarchy?

Tags: python, pandas, data-structures, hierarchy, levels

My imported data from excel has been multi indexed with the time stamp column in Pandas. I would like place the remaining columns into their respective hierarchical groups. The frequency band columns **(7 columns: delta', 'theta', 'alpha', 'beta', 'high beta', 'gamma')** under the hierarchy column labeled 'EMG' and the biological measures (**2 columns: 'Heart Rate Variabilty' and 'GSR')** under 'Biofeedback'.

Is there a straight forward way to do this?

The second part is, how can a single level dataframe be appended to this multi index hierarchical dataframe without flattening the hierarchy created in the first part?

Comment: Not enough information, can you please add a snapshot of the data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create [`MultiIndex.from_arrays`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_arrays.html) and then [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
cols = ['delta','theta','alpha','beta','Heart Rate Variabilty','high beta', 'gamma','GSR']
df = pd.DataFrame([[4,5,8,3,1,0,9,2]], columns=cols)    
print (df)
   delta  theta  alpha  beta  Heart Rate Variabilty  high beta  gamma  GSR
0      4      5      8     3                      1          0      9    2   

c1 = ['delta', 'theta', 'alpha', 'beta','high beta', 'gamma']
c2 = ['Heart Rate Variabilty', 'GSR']  


mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([ ['EMG'] * len(c1) + ['Biofeedback'] * len(c2),c1 + c2])
print (mux)
MultiIndex(levels=[['Biofeedback', 'EMG'], 
                   ['GSR', 'Heart Rate Variabilty', 'alpha', 'beta',
                    'delta', 'gamma', 'high beta', 'theta']],
           labels=[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [4, 7, 2, 3, 6, 5, 1, 0]])

df = df.reindex(columns=mux, level=1)
print (df)
    EMG                                            Biofeedback    
  delta theta alpha beta high beta gamma Heart Rate Variabilty GSR
0     4     5     8    3         0     9                     1   2
```

EDIT by comment:

Thank you for final solution OP:

```
df1.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(c, '', '') for c in df1])
df = pd.concat([df, df1], axis=1)
```

Comment: If use `MultiIndex`, then all columns have to be `MultiIndex` too.

Comment: Thanks @jezrael. Deleted previous comment by mistake. How would I include two original columns to df from the imported data as it did not need to be hierarchical?

Comment: Ia m not sure if understand, can you create some sample data?

Comment: so how can i add these two columns to multi index without assigning any other columns to it?

Comment: Do you think `df = pd.concat([df, df1], axis=1)` ? Only guess it.

Comment: yes this is possible if i create df1 with just those two columns but to explain using your code: cols = ['delta','theta','alpha','beta','Heart Rate Variabilty','high beta', 'gamma','GSR', 'Gender', 'Location']
df = pd.DataFrame([[4,5,8,3,1,0,9,2,Female, Leg]], columns=cols)

Comment: Thank you. What is Female and Leg ? strings or variables ? Do you need add another `df2` ?

Comment: Yes both Gender and Location columns are string. So Gender value will be either male or female and Location has 5 string values. Maybe creating it as another dataframe will work however they are linked by the inital time stamp multi indexing. Just wondering if it could be done by adding a blank row so that the arrays are of the same length, since Gender and Location are not grouped into a hierarchical column

Comment: I dont understand. Output has MultiIndex - hierarchical index. So if add new column(s), output has to be Multiindex too. If need mixed columns (not Multiindex) with MultiIndex columns together, it is impossible.

Comment: do you need add another dataframe to `MultiIndex`ed `df` created by `df = df.reindex(columns=mux, level=1)`? Or something else? Sorry:(

Comment: yes it worked perfectly when i added  df1.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(c, '', '') for c in df1]) prior to df = pd.concat([df, df1], axis=1) - shall edit question to include solution